# Combining two Immutable lists with inject

Tags: list, groovy, immutability, inject

I have two lists that consist of strings, both immmutable:

```
def list1 = [ "A", "B", "C" ]
list2 = ["D", "E", F"]
```

List 2 is being returned by a custom function I have made. Is there a way to take these two immutable lists and combine both of their elements with inject? I have tried numerous combinations without success. I have googled extensively for this. I cannot change this to a mutable list. I am aware that it would be much easier to simply combine two lists then make them immutable, but alas, this is not what I am aiming for.

Following is the desired output:

```
[ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", F"]
```

The solution here will be used to solve a larger problem. I am merely simplifying this to the base case.

Thank you.

Edit: I have to use the inject method. I am aware that I can simply use + or iterate through each list with a loop to get the desired result. This is strictly limited to using .inject in Groovy.

Comment: How is this [tag:java]?

Comment: Groovy is based on a java platform. But ok tag was removed. That's fine.

Comment: Show a sample how you want to see the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Set as Immutable
def list1 = ["A", "B", "C"].asImmutable() 
def list2 = ["D", "E", "F"].asImmutable() 

//Supports Immutablity
try {list1 << 'Z'} catch(e){assert e instanceof UnsupportedOperationException} 
try {list2 << 'Z'} catch(e){assert e instanceof UnsupportedOperationException}

//Desired result using "inject"
def result = list2.inject(list1){init, val -> [init] << val}.flatten()
assert result == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'] 

//Immutable Test
assert list1 == ["A", "B", "C"] 
assert list2 == ["D", "E", "F"]

//Supports Immutablity after operation
try {list1 << 'Z'} catch(e){assert e instanceof UnsupportedOperationException}
try {list2 << 'Z'} catch(e){assert e instanceof UnsupportedOperationException}
```

Comment: Inside the closure I am getting stuck. I want to use list1 once while calling a returnValue function to generate the proper entry in the next element of the list. T

Comment: @DaGr8Gatzby `init` inside the closure represents `list1` since `list1` has been specified as the head of the list by specifying as a parameter to `inject`. Have a close look at [this example](http://bit.ly/1cButN3) in the API.

Comment: The main problem in my code is that I only have list1 available to me while list2 is generated by a separate function. I then need to ensure the entire collection is built by constantly adding the result (tail) to initial.

Comment: Well, when `list2` is generated fully, you can use the above code. Can't it be done? Will `list2` not be available fully by the time you use the inject operation? @DaGr8Gatzby

Comment: I need to be able to make an immutable collection for each pass. Is there anyway I can run the innards of the closure 8 times?

Comment: I did it dmahapatro. Ty.